# ClassCastException for <h:selectManyCheckbox> with validation on ajax update when INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL is active

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.3, selectmanycheckbox

I have a `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` that has a required-validation on. If I submit the form, I get a validation error when nothing is selected. So far, this ist expected. However, if I do an ajax update on the checkbox then, I get a `ClassCastException`. But only if empty values are treated as `null`.

So, I have the following setup. In the `web.xml` I set

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then I have an xhtml-page like this:

```
<h:form id="main">
  <h:selectManyCheckbox id="value" value="#{testcb.selected}" required="true" requiredMessage="Select at least one entry">
    <f:selectItems value="#{testcb.available}"/>
  </h:selectManyCheckbox>
  <div><h:message for="value" style="color:red;"/></div>

  <h:outputLabel for="checkit" value="Enter some text: "/>
  <h:inputText id="checkit" value="#{testcb.text}">
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render=":main:value"/>
  </h:inputText>

  <div><h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" action="#{testcb.action}"/></div>
</h:form>
```

And this backing bean:

```
@Named("testcb")
@SessionScoped
public class TestCBBean implements Serializable {

  private final Set<TestValue> available = EnumSet.allOf(TestValue.class);
  private final Set<TestValue> selected = EnumSet.noneOf(TestValue.class);
  private String text;

  public void action() {}

  public Set<TestValue> getAvailable() { return available; }

  public void setAvailable(Set<TestValue> available) {
    this.available.clear();
    this.available.addAll(available);
  }

  public Set<TestValue> getSelected() { return selected; }

  public void setSelected(Set<TestValue> selected) {
    this.selected.clear();
    this.selected.addAll(selected);
  }

  public String getText() { return text; }

  public void setText(String text) { this.text = text; }
}
```

And this `enum`:

```
public enum TestValue { ONE, TWO, THREE }
```

I am running this in Wildfly 26.0.1-Final (JavaEE 8). But this also happens in older versions (like Wildfly 15). What I am doing:

[image: screenshot of UI]

1. enter some text and leave the box: an ajax update runs setting the value successfully in the model
2. I press submit: the validation error for the empty checkboxes pops up
3. I modify the text in the input and leave the box: the ajax update results in the following Exception:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object; (java.lang.String and [Ljava.lang.Object; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
      com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.17.SP01//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getSubmittedSelectedValues(MenuRenderer.java:508)
      com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.17.SP01//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.java:89)
      javax.faces.api@3.1.0.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:600)
      javax.faces.api@3.1.0.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1655)
      com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.17.SP01//com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:628)
      com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.17.SP01//com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:159)
      javax.faces.api@3.1.0.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
      javax.faces.api@3.1.0.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1469)
      javax.faces.api@3.1.0.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:355)
```

On the ajax update the checkboxes are not submitted. But they seem to contain an empty string as submitted value from the validation step before.

When setting the context parameter to `false` this works. But I want to keep it on `true`. Any ideas how I could work around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reproduced. This is indeed a bug in Mojarra.

It boils down to that the following method in `UIInput` superclass ...

```
@Override
public Object getSubmittedValue() {
    if (submittedValue == null && !isValid() && considerEmptyStringNull(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return submittedValue;
    }
}
```

... is **not** overridden in `UISelectMany` superclass in such way that it returns `new String[0]` instead of `""`. This was an oversight during implementing [Faces issue 671](https://github.com/jakartaee/faces/issues/671).

I have fixed it in [Mojarra issue 5081](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/5081).

In the meanwhile, until you can upgrade to the Mojarra version containing the fix, you can temporarily work around it by copy pasting the entire [source code](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/2.3/impl/src/main/java/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.java) file of `UISelectMany` into your project while maintaining the package and adding the following method to it:

```
@Override
public Object getSubmittedValue() {
    Object submittedValue = super.getSubmittedValue();
    return "".equals(submittedValue) ? new String[0] : submittedValue;
}
```

Comment: Wow cool! Thanks a lot for fixing this right away!